# Parcel+Sass+npm: "Error: Failed to install @parcel/transformer-sass: Callback must be a function. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, parceljs

I'm trying to use Parcel to build a library, and am trying to import an `index.scss` file into my `index.js` file, it either fails to 'install @parcel/transformer-sass' if I don't include it as a dependency, or 'cannot find module "@parcel/transformer-sass"' when I do install it.  Notably, Parcel will build successfully if I import an `index.css' file into` index.js` instead.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Installing `npm i @parcel/transformer-scss` as a dependency, for which I get the error:

```
× Build failed.

Error: Failed to install @parcel/transformer-sass: Callback must be a function. Received undefined

  Error: Failed to install @parcel/transformer-sass: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
  at install
  (C:\...\nvm\v14.18.0\node_modules\parcel\node_modules\@parcel\package-manager\lib\installPackage.js:131:11)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
  at async PromiseQueue._runFn
  (C:\...\nvm\v14.18.0\node_modules\parcel\node_modules\@parcel\utils\lib\PromiseQueue.js:88:7)
  at async PromiseQueue._next
  (C:\...\nvm\v14.18.0\node_modules\parcel\node_modules\@parcel\utils\lib\PromiseQueue.js:75:5)
```

Installing `@parcel/transformer-sass` and `@parcel/config-default`, for which I  receive the error:

```
× Build failed.

@parcel/core: Cannot find Parcel plugin "@parcel/transformer-sass"

  C:\...\nvm\v14.18.0\node_modules\parcel\node_modules\@parcel\config-default\index.json:25:23
    24 |     "*.{styl,stylus}": ["@parcel/transformer-stylus"],
  > 25 |     "*.{sass,scss}": ["@parcel/transformer-sass"],
  >    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Cannot find module "@parcel/transformer-sass"
    26 |     "*.less": ["@parcel/transformer-less"],
    27 |     "*.{css,pcss}": ["@parcel/transformer-postcss", "@parcel/transformer-css"],
```

I also tried creating a `.parcelrc` of various configurations, including:

```
{
"transformers":{".scss":"@parcel/transformer-scss"}
}
```

and

```
{
"extends":"@parcel/config-default",
"transformers":{".scss":"@parcel/transformer-scss"}
}
```

which throw similar errors.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "targets": {
    "default": {
      "distDir": "../staticfiles"
    }
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "module.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "parcel watch",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@parcel/config-default": "^2.0.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-table": "^1.18.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

here's my `index.js`:

```
import "./index.scss";
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-table';
import $ from "jquery";
console.log($)


window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

console.log("hello world");

$(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  })
```

Here's my `index.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table";
// @import "bootstrap-table/dist/extenstions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control";

$body-color: slateblue;

body {
  color: $body-color;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: If you go into `your-project/node_modules/@parcel`, do you see a `transformer-sass` folder? The errors you're getting seem to indicate be rooted in parcel being unable to find that package. Parcel will automatically try to install it for you, so to simplify things and isolate the problem, you can try running `parcel` with the `--no-autoinstall` flag and then install it manually with npm (and see if you get any errors).

Comment: Also, the package name is `@parcel/transformer-sass`, _not_ `@parcel/transformer-scss`, as you have in a few places above. Maybe try everything again and pay really close attention to the spelling?

Comment: `@parcel/transformer-scss` was a typo.  I went and checked in `node-modules/@parcel` and there wasn't a `transformer-sass`.  I installed transform-sass separately, and re-ran  `parcel --no-autoinstall` and received the `cannot find module "@parcel/transformer-sass"` errror.  FWIW I also re-ran `parcel watch`  and got the `Failed to install @parcel/transformer-sass: Callback must be a function. Received undefined` error again.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to confirm, after you "installed transformer-sass manually", you confirmed that there was a `node_modules/@parcel/transformer-sass` folder? If it's not there, that's the cause, and we'd want to zoom in on what's going wrong with `npm install`. Would it be possible to share a reproduction repo?

Comment: That's correct.  I checked `node-modules/@parcel` and there wasn't `trasnformer-sass`. 
 I ran `npm i @parcel/transformer-sass` and rechecked `node-modules` and `transformer-sass` was there.  After I confirmed that transformer-sass was in node-modules, I re-ran `parcel watch --no-autoinstall` and it threw the `cannot find module` error, and it threw the `failed to load module` error when I ran `parcel watch` without `auto-install`.   I also tried re-running it both with and without a `.parcelrc` file with the `transformer-scss` corrected, with the same results

Comment: When I try copying your `package.json`, `index.js`, and `index.scss` from your question into a project, running `npm install` / `npm run build`, I don't see the same errors that you are. Can you share a repo where you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to figure out how to restore my project after accidentally deleting it while trying to set up a repo to share.  Here it is: [here it is](https://github.com/askmydog/Parcel-test)

Comment: When I run `npm install` / `npm build` on that repo, I get the error `@parcel/transformer-sass: Can't find stylesheet to import`, which is different from the original question (and actually indicates that the original problem is fixed - `@parcel/transformer-sass` can't give you diagnostics, unless it's installed correctly :-) ). Is that what you see? If so, I can help with that, too - just want to confirm.

Comment: Actually no, I ran the repo after I set it up to make sure I could reproduce the errors, and it was (is) still throwing the same errors.

Comment: I think I'm stumped then - there might be something lurking in the details about exactly how you get that repo into the state where `parcel build` is throwing `@parcel/core: Cannot find Parcel plugin "@parcel/transformer-sass"` errors. If you can spell things out more explicitly, I'm happy to take another crack at it.

Comment: having exact same issue and none of the solutions I have found actually work

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with running the parcel, probably due to a node.js update, I updated the parcel and installed `@parcel/transformer-sass` there: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@parcel/transformer-sass.
After that, the parcel works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of `Callback must be a function. Received undefined` occurs when using parcel in a project directory that has a parent directory with an (unrelated) `yarn.lock` file.

To reproduce run `touch ~/yarn.lock` and then run parcel in a subdirectory of `~/`.

To fix the issue delete any `yarn.lock` files in parent directories.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar bug, consider this:
You should try deleting completely node_modules,
then run `npm i`, which should reinstall node_modules with the correct path to `@parcel/transformer-sass`.
After this is confirmed, run `npm start`. This should build successfully.